# GraphQL-java: Error: Introspection result missing interfaces

Tags: graphql-java

I just started using GraphQL and I have some problems getting it to work.
I get `Error: Introspection result missing interfaces` no matter what kind of schema I have.

Schema:

```
schema {
    query: Query
}

type Query {
    dd: String
}
```

Result from GraphiQL:

```
Error: Introspection result missing interfaces: {"kind":"OBJECT","name":"Query","fields":[{"name":"dd","type":{"kind":"SCALAR","name":"String"},"isDeprecated":false}]}
    at E (file:///C:/Program%20Files/GraphiQL/resources/app.asar/dist/bundle.js:32:22809)
    at _ (file:///C:/Program%20Files/GraphiQL/resources/app.asar/dist/bundle.js:32:22340)
    at r (file:///C:/Program%20Files/GraphiQL/resources/app.asar/dist/bundle.js:32:21822)
    at file:///C:/Program%20Files/GraphiQL/resources/app.asar/dist/bundle.js:32:25249
    at Array.map (native)
    at i (file:///C:/Program%20Files/GraphiQL/resources/app.asar/dist/bundle.js:32:25226)
    at file:///C:/Program%20Files/GraphiQL/resources/app.asar/dist/bundle.js:26:30839
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

No matter what I change, I still get this fault except it references different places when I change the variable names.
Is there something I have misunderstood?

I'm using graphql-java with Spring Boot and the setup is rather basic:

```
@RestController
public class GraphQLEndpoint {

    @Autowired
    private GraphQL graphQL;

    @PostMapping(path = "/graphql", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    Map<String, Object> graphql(@RequestBody GraphQLRequest request, WebRequest webRequest) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, JsonProcessingException {
        val query = nonNull(request.getQuery()) ? request.getQuery() : "";
        val variables = (Map<String, Object>) (nonNull(request.getVariables()) ? request.getVariables() : emptyMap());

        val executionInput = ExecutionInput.newExecutionInput()
                .query(query)
                .operationName(request.getOperationName())
                .variables(variables)
                .build();

        return graphQL.execute(executionInput).toSpecification();
    }
}

@Configuration
public class GraphQLConfig {

    @Bean
    GraphQL graphQL(@Value("${classpath:schemas/pdl.graphqls}") ClassPathResource schemaFile) throws IOException {
        val typeRegistry = new SchemaParser().parse(schemaFile.getFile());
        val runtimeWiring = RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()
                .type(typeRuntimeWiring())
                .build();
        val schema = new SchemaGenerator().makeExecutableSchema(typeRegistry, runtimeWiring);
        return GraphQL.newGraphQL(schema).build();
    }

    private TypeRuntimeWiring typeRuntimeWiring() {
        return TypeRuntimeWiring.newTypeWiring("Query")
                .dataFetcher("dd", environment -> "test")
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the property in jackson to ignore non_empty lists, which made GraphiQL and Altair throw and exception.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs when the *interfaces* property expected by GraphiQL is absent in the response.

When using **graphql-java-servlet** - Defining **GraphQLObjectMapper** with appropriate configuration helps i.e not setting serialization property to **JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL** so that *interfaces* property is present.

```
   @Bean
   public GraphQLObjectMapper graphQLObjectMapper() {
       return GraphQLObjectMapper.newBuilder()
               .withObjectMapperProvider(ObjectMapper::new)
               .build();
   }
```